# How easy / expensive is it to move kitchen from front to back of the house?

Tags: kitchens

Good afternoon,

My partner and I (who have absolutely no design / construction experience) have found almost the ideal house - just within budget - but the only problem is that the kitchen is a situated at the front of the house (and is a little small).[image]

We are considering whether to put an offer in on the house, but would like to know how easy / costly it would be to move the kitchen to the back of the property (perhaps where the current dining room is) so that it leads onto the (lovely) big garden.

Any comments / advice would be extremely welcome. Floor plan attached.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but this is far too broad and subjective a question for our Q&A format. Also, we don't have nearly enough information even if it was appropriate. I suggest consulting with a local expert.

Comment: This is too broad, etc. Too many variables. But the biggest factor is moving the plumbing. I have a hunch your upstairs plumbing is all along the front wall too. Assuming that's the case, you will need essentially all new plumbing in the new kitchen area - hot, cold, drain as noted in an answer. So an absolutely key question is: **is there a basement underneath with easy access to route pipes from the front towards the back**? With that, this is potentially practical. Without that, I'd definitely recommend against it.

Comment: Consult with a contractor or architect

Comment: Agree that there's a *lot* of factors that will affect the price, but as an order of magnitude estimate, you may be looking at a few tens of thousands of dollars.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to give any accurate estimates on cost with the information given. In a very broad scope, you'd need to bring hot, cold water and a drain into the new area and would probably have to tear up the flooring to do that. You'd also need about six electrical circuits for a disposal, refrig, dishwasher and countertop outlets plus a 240V line for your range/oven. The walls in the new area would have to be supported to install the kitchen cabinets.

Answer (score 1):

Merely remodeling a kitchen **in the same place** is expensive. Moving it will cost even more.

Kitchens in involve

- water supply
- waste water removal
- waste water venting
- extensive electrical supply
- typically ventilation (a range hood)

  and depending on the area or your preferred cooking method,
- gas supply

  (pipeline or bottled, depending on the location - piping in the house in either case.)